# Reducer in redux is not activating

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state

I am trying to update state each time I type into an input. The action creator is firing but the reducer is not and I am not sure why. Below is the component and the reducer file. I have commented where the console.log works and where is does not. Some suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

//Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  updateName,
  updateAddress,
  updateCity,
  updateState,
  updateZip
} from "../../redux/reducers/reducer";

class StepOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="name">
          <h3>Property Name</h3>
          <input
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            onChange={e => updateName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="address">
          <h3>Address</h3>
          <input
            name="address"
            placeholder="Address"
            onChange={e => updateAddress(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="city">
          <h3>City</h3>
          <input
            name="city"
            placeholder="City"
            onChange={e => updateCity(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="state">
          <h3>State</h3>
          <input
            name="state"
            placeholder="State"
            onChange={e => updateState(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="zip">
          <h3>Zip</h3>
          <input
            name="zip"
            placeholder="Zip"
            onChange={e => updateZip(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <Link to="/wizard/step_two">
          <button onClick={console.log(this.props)}>Next Step</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    state
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    updateName,
    updateAddress,
    updateCity,
    updateState,
    updateZip
  }
)(StepOne);
```

//Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  name: "",
  address: "",
  city: "",
  state: "",
  zip: 0,
  image: "",
  monthly_mortgage: 0,
  desired_rent: 0,
  houses: []
};

const NAME_INPUT = "NAME_INPUT";
const ADDRESS_INPUT = "ADDRESS";
const CITY_INPUT = "CITY_INPUT";
const STATE_INPUT = "STATE_INPUT";
const ZIP_INPUT = "ZIP_INPUT";
const IMAGE_INPUT = "IMAGE_INPUT";
const MORTGAGE_INPUT = "MORTGAGE_INPUT";
const DESIRED_RENT_INPUT = "DESIRED_RENT_INPUT";

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log("REDUCER HIT: Action ->", action); // console.log does not work

  switch (action.type) {
    case NAME_INPUT:
      return { ...state, name: action.payload };
    case ADDRESS_INPUT:
      return { ...state, address: action.payload };
    case CITY_INPUT:
      return { ...state, city: action.payload };
    case STATE_INPUT:
      return { ...state, state: action.payload };
    case ZIP_INPUT:
      return { ...state, zip: action.payload };
    case IMAGE_INPUT:
      return { ...state, image: action.payload };
    case MORTGAGE_INPUT:
      return { ...state, monthly_mortgage: action.payload };
    case DESIRED_RENT_INPUT:
      return { ...state, desired_rent: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function updateName(name) {
  console.log(name); // console.log is working
  return {
    type: NAME_INPUT,
    payload: name
  };
}

export function updateAddress(address) {
  return {
    type: ADDRESS_INPUT,
    payload: address
  };
}

export function updateCity(city) {
  return {
    type: CITY_INPUT,
    payload: city
  };
}

export function updateState(state) {
  return {
    type: STATE_INPUT,
    payload: state
  };
}

export function updateZip(zip) {
  return {
    type: ZIP_INPUT,
    payload: zip
  };
}

export default reducer;
```

//Store

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducers/reducer";

export default createStore(reducer);
```

Comment: I am exporting the reducer, accidently left it off of the code. Ill post the store here one sec.

Comment: ah I see the problem now, will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your action creators directly from import, but for them to have the full `redux` flow, you need to use them from `this.props` e.g:

```
this.props.updateName()
```

The second parameter of the `connect()` function maps `dispatch` to your action creators, so your actions can be dispatched to the root reducer.